# Reassigning $this in PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel, object

I have a class A which extends class B

```
class A extends B{
    function home(){
        $site = new SitesController($this);
        return $site->home();
    }
}
```

I want every variables in this class to be availabe in SitesController class. But I dont want to extend SitesController from A since everytime it is called everything would be re-initialized and there would be a lot of repeated query calls.
So I tried to pass $this when the class is created. But I cant reinitialize $this in SitesController like this.

```
class SitesController implements SiteInterface
{
    function __construct($data) {
        $this = $data;
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can make this work??
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by: _everything would be re-initialized and there would be a lot of repeated query calls_

Comment: @Daan In the constructor of parent class B, I have a lot of database query calls. And in constructor of Class A, I have called parent::__construct(); and if I extend SitesController from class A i have to do the same in its constructor. The queries would be called once in Class B's constructor and again in SitesControllers constructor. Isn't that the case? I'm not that sure though.

Comment: Yes that's correct, couldn't see from the code you where initializing the parent's class, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "reassign" $this.

But you can assign your instance of A as a property of SitesController, which means that you can access all public methods/properties of A from within your SitesController instance.

```
class SitesController implements SiteInterface
{
    protected $A;

    public function __construct(A $data) {
        $this->A = $data;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        return $this->A->publicMethodOfA();
    }
}
```

This is "Dependency Injection", and is applying the principle of Composition rather than Inheritence

Comment: Any particular reason why you make `$A` protected and not private ?

Comment: @Daan - purely to facilitate any future extensions from SitesController.... As a general principle, I'll only ever make something private if it absolutely needs to be private